# Можно ли динамически переименовывать имена файлов ресурсов, при помощи AssetBundle?

Tags: yii, yii2

Я заметил что при использовании AssetBundle класса, создаются папки с ресурсами, причем имена папок постоянно меняются, видимо это хэш. Для поддержки версионности файлов ресурсов, было бы хорошо их так-же динамически переименовывать.

**ВОПРОС:** Можно ли динамически  переименовывать имена файлов ресурсов, при помощи AssetBundle?

/P.s/
Спасибо за внимание.

Приложение:

```
   <?php
   namespace app\assets;

   use yii\web\AssetBundle;
    class NavbarAsset extends AssetBundle
    {
        public $sourcePath = '@app/components/widgets/assets';
        public $css = [
            'css/general_style-min.css',
        ];
        public $js = [
            //'js/lib/jquery-2.2.0.min.js',
            'js/lib/jquery.color-2.1.0.min.js',
            'js/navbar-min.js',
        ];
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Для этих целей в Yii2 assetBundle есть специальное свойство appendTimestamp.
Вот ссылка на [офф. руководство](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-web-assetmanager.html#$appendTimestamp-detail).

Вот как это используется:
в конфигурационном файле надо прописать

```
return [
'components' => [
    'assetManager' => [
        'class' => 'yii\web\AssetManager',
        'appendTimestamp' => true,
    ],
    // ...
],
```

]

Comment: а что оно делает ?  не ясно пока, пробую ничего не вижу

Comment: Добавляет штамп времени в конце файла в качестве параметра. 
`<link href="/css/site.css?v=1455877765" rel="stylesheet">` к примеру.
Если изменить файл, тогда цифры после ?v= поменяются, что заставит браузер загрузить новую версию файла, а не брать ее из кэша. Так же это касается и кэширующих прокси серверов.

Comment: Странно, почему то не работает. У меня какие были ссылки , такие и остались.

Comment: может что то еще нужно добавить кроме этого кода в конфигурационный файл?

Comment: нет, больше ничего. Вот код внутри AssetManager.php фреймворка, отрабатывающий этот момент:
    if ($this->appendTimestamp && ($timestamp = @filemtime("$basePath/$asset")) > 0) {
            return "$baseUrl/$asset?v=$timestamp";
        } else {
            return "$baseUrl/$asset";
        }

Comment: Да, у меня он есть. Но почему же не работает...Хм.

Comment: во! Заработало! То я не сохранил конфиг файл)) Спасибо!

Comment: А можно ли как то удалять автоматически папки с ресурсами, или менять их имена. А то я постоянно их в ручную удаляю.

Comment: А зачем удаляете?

Comment: что бы погрузились ресурсы с измененными данными. Если мы изменим что то к примеру в css, то пока те папки не удалишь, новые ресурсы не подгрузяться.

Comment: Логика Yii2 предусматривает, при правильной настройки AssetBundle, изменение файла в папке assets. Сам Yii2 его и переписывает. Проверьте как вы написали свой класс.

Comment: я обновил свой вопрос, посмотрите пожалуйста. Вставил туда класс -AssetBundle

Comment: Возможно ошибка самого framework 
Вот [тут](http://www.yiiframework.ru/forum/viewtopic.php?t=21642) такое-же поведение описано

Comment: Я не уверен, может вот ответ: baseUrl: задаёт URL соответствующий директории basePath. Также как и для basePath, если Вы задаёте свойство sourcePath(#asset-manager) опубликует ресурсы и перезапишет это свойство соответственно. Здесь могут быть использованы псевдонимы путей.